# History of multi-factor authentication

Tags: two-factor-authentication

This may look a bit strange, but I could not find any reference online regarding the first in history multi-factor authentication.
I know FFIEC has [published](http://www.ffiec.gov/press/pr101205.htm) a requirement for ebanking systems in 2005, but with could not find what systems existed at that time or  before that.
[RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt) for HOTP (which is now a de-facto standard for 2FA) is dated 2005.
As of right now, the oldest two-factor system I can find is [mOTP](http://motp.sourceforge.net/), its news section has dates in 2003.

Does anyone has more reliable info on this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: RSA SecurId tokens were one of the first. Not sure exactly when they came out but it was before 1993

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article on Two-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication) begins with referring to a 1984 [US4720860 patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US4720860) for a *"Method and apparatus for positively identifying an individual"*.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. My question was more about first implementations, what the patent provides is more the theory behind.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to find such information. Many implementations of MFA are probably classified as trade- or state secrets and are not public.

Comment: does it mean that MobileOTP is the first MFA implementation?